# Задержка при вызове событий OnMouse()

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал собственный `Control` для всех кнопок, чтобы все кнопки имели графический вид. Пример кода:

```
public class FlatButton : Control
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Backaground for non active button.
    /// </summary>
    public Image backgroundNormal { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Background for active button.
    /// </summary>
    public Image backgroundActive { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Background for hover/pressed button.
    /// </summary>
    public Image backgroundHover { get; set; }

    public FlatButton()
    {
        // Nothing
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeave(e);
        base.BackgroundImage = backgroundNormal;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseHover(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseHover(e);
        base.BackgroundImage = backgroundHover;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        base.BackgroundImage = backgroundActive;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        base.BackgroundImage = backgroundHover;
    }
}
```

Однако в приложении замечена задержка (где-то 300-400 мс) на вызов всех событий `OnMouse()`. Возможно ли её убрать в `WinForms` проекте?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С задержкой происходит событие `Hover`. Это его стандартное поведение.

Полагаю, вам нужно заменить `OnMouseHover` на `OnMouseEnter` - это событие будет срабатывать сразу же.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, `OnMouseHover()` событие имеет задержку. Всё заработало без лагов.